# VS 201x - How do downloaded Bower .js files get deployed?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, bower, asp.net-core

**Waffle**

I've now been trying to automate and sort out a VS2013, not vNext, ASP.NET MVC project that started life as a front-end project on a Mac by a digital agency!

Aside: I've not yet used VS 2015, or ASP.NET vNext.

It uses npm, grunt and bower but not in the new VS 2015 template project way. We have to manually install the CLI tools and invoke it all manually, and it fails behind our proxy.

No one really understands this stuff or has the appetite to really tackle the problem. We copy files from a share to fudge it into working. It's a mess.

**My Question**

One of the things that's completely baffling me is how the dynamically-downloaded JavaScript files, via Bower, can be deployed via MSDeploy.

When a deployment package ZIP is created, it only includes content files declared the `.csproj` file.

In VS2015 there some kind of mechanism that auto-adds the downloaded Bower packages to the project?

Or some other trick?

Is there something that'll do this for VS 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Not exclusive to Visual Studio 2015, but part of the ASP.NET 5 tooling.  You can add an array of "prepublish" commands to your project.json that basically become part of the build/publish pipeline. Therefore, ensuring that Gulp, Bower or NPM commands can be run before the MSDeploy publish happens and are ready to be picked up by MSDeploy for publishing.

Reference:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#publishing